# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 1258

Tags: java, gson

I am getting the following error when trying to deserialize from JSON:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 1258
```

Comment: Have you checked the JSON to see if it is valid? What does `l_sParamProcessedImage` contain? Does it match up to the structure of `ToggleProcessedImage`? Please post the JSON you are attempting to deserialize, as well as the source for `ToggleProcessedImage`.

Comment: yes i have posted the value of l_sParamProcessedImage. yes it matches the source of toogleProcessedImage

Comment: Not that I don't believe you, but it helps to have more eyes on it :) - can you post the source of `ToggleProcessedImage` as well?

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't posted the source to `ToggleProcessedImage` (or any of the objects that it may itself contain), I cannot really tell you why your JSON isn't deserializing. Gson expects an array for a particular field, but the JSON seems to contain an object for that field.

I looked at column 1258 (where the error happens) in your JSON and see that it is:

```
"MeasuredBox": {
   ...
}
```

Now earlier, you also have:

```
"MeasuredBoxes": [
    ...
]
```

Is it possible that in one of the classes, you have accidentally defined the type of the `measuredBox` field to be `List<MeasuredBox>` or `MeasuredBox[]` instead of just `MeasuredBox`? Perhaps you got it confused with the similarly-named field `measuredBoxes`.

**EDIT**

In response to your comment. You posted that `MeasuredBoxes` is:

```
public class MeasuredBoxes {

    public Box Region; 
    public List<Integer> LayerBottoms; 
    public List<Measurement> Measurements; 
    public List<Box> MeasuredBox; //<--- this is the source of your error

    ...
}
```

That's your error right there. The `MeasuredBoxes` class expects a list of `Box` objects for the `MeasuredBox` property. However, the JSON you're supplying only has a single `Box` that is represented directly as an object.

To fix this, you either need to change your JSON such that `MeasuredBox` is an array:

```
"MeasuredBox": [{
   ...
}]
```

Or change the `MeasuredBoxes` class such that the `MeasuredBox` field is of type `Box` and not `List<Box>`:

```
public class MeasuredBoxes {

    public Box Region; 
    public List<Integer> LayerBottoms; 
    public List<Measurement> Measurements; 
    public Box MeasuredBox; //<--- this is Box now instead of List<Box>

    ...
}
```

On another note, please use Java naming conventions. Variables (this includes class fields) and methods should be `namedLikeThis` (i.e., camel-cased) and `NotLikeThis`, but classes should be `NamedLikeThis`.

It is also preferable to keep class members `private`; making them `public` is the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: In the MasuredBoxes I have a Region, LayerBottom and a list of MeasuredBox so I didnt get confused. there will be a list of MeasuredBox

Comment: @PSDebugger Please post the source `ToggleProcessedImage` and any internal objects that it also uses. Otherwise we're simply playing a guessing game.

Comment: public Box Region; // required
  public List<Integer> LayerBottoms; // required
  public List<Measurement> Measurements; // required
  public List<Box> MeasuredBox; // required